# How to prove this challenging inequality?

Tags: inequality

Assume that $a$, $b$, $c$ are real numbers between $-1$ and $1$, and satisfy $a+b+c=0$. Please help to prove the following inequality:
$$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2+|a^2-b^2|+|b^2-c^2|+|c^2-a^2| \ge 4(|a|^3+|b|^3+|c|^3).$$
I have verified it via many random numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First consider the case that at least one of $a,b,c$ is zero. Without loss of generality assume $c=0$ and $a\ge0$ (so $b=-a\le0$). The inequality becomes
$$(2a)^2+a^2+a^2+0+a^2+a^2\ge 4a^3+4a^3$$
If $a=0$ then it becomes $0\ge0$ which is true. If $a\ne0$ we divide both sides by $8a^2$, yielding
$$1\ge a$$
which is true by the problem's assumption.

Then we consider the case that $a,b,c$ are all nonzero. Because $a+b+c=0$, the real numbers $a,b,c$ cannot be all negative or all positive. Therefore exactly one or two of them are positive.

Consider that the signs of $a,b,c$ can be flipped (together) while keeping both sides of the inequality the same. (For example, $a=-1/2,b=1/4,c=1/4$ to $a=1/2,b=-1/4,c=-1/4$.) Therefore we can assume without loss of generality that two of the numbers, say $a$ and $b$, are positive. Assume further that $a\ge b$, so we have $c=-a-b\le 0\le b\le a$.

Recall the inequality to be proved:

$$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2+|a^2-b^2|+|b^2-c^2|+|c^2-a^2|\ge4(|a|^3+|b|^3+|c|^3)$$

The left hand side of the inequality becomes

$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2+(a^2-b^2)+(c^2-b^2)+(c^2-a^2)$

$=2a^2+2b^2+2c^2-2ab-2bc-2ca+2c^2-2b^2$

$=2a^2+4c^2-2ab-2bc-2ca$

$=2a^2+4c^2-2ab-2c(a+b)$

$=2a^2+6c^2-2ab$

$=2a^2+6(a+b)^2-2ab$

$=8a^2+6b^2+10ab$

and the right hand side becomes

$4(a^3+b^3+(a+b)^3)$

$=4((a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2+(a+b)^2))$

$=4(a+b)(2a^2+2b^2+ab)$

Therefore the inequality becomes
$$8a^2+6b^2+10ab-4(a+b)(2a^2+2b^2+ab)\ge0$$
$$4a^2+3b^2+5ab+2(-a-b)(2a^2+2b^2+ab)\ge0$$
$$-b^2+3ab+2(1-a-b)(2a^2+2b^2+ab)\ge0$$
$$(3a-b)b+2(1-a-b)(2a^2+2b^2+ab)\ge0$$
Recall that $a\ge b$ from our assumption, so $3a-b$ is positive, and $1-a-b=1+c\ge 0$ because $c\ge-1$. Therefore the left hand side of the above inequality is positive, and we are done.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much.

Comment: This is a more complicated version of this inequality. Do you have any suggestions?   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4734112/how-to-prove-this-difficult-symmetric-inequality