# How to prove this difficult (symmetric) inequality?

Tags: inequality

I am having trouble with proving the following inequality.
Assume that $a,b,c,d$ are real numbers between $-1$ and $1$. Define Define $X=a-b,\, Y=b-c,\, Z=c-d,\, W=d-a$. Then
\begin{multline} 
(X-Y)^2+(Y-Z)^2+(Z-W)^2+(W-X)^2 \\ 
\qquad{}+|X^2-Y^2|+|Y^2-Z^2|+|Z^2-W^2|+|W^2-X^2| \\
\geq 2\bigl( |X|^3+|Y|^3+|Z|^3+|W|^3 \bigr).
\end{multline}

I have verified this inequality by using a lot of random numbers. Could anyone have any suggestions for proving it?

Comment: [Very similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4734058/how-to-prove-this-challenging-inequality)

Comment: Much more difficult than that one.